# ul and li like this example in photo inbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

i have a sidebar with a list of links
how can i do the vertical line that connect between title of list and other under list
[image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAywu.png)

and my code html :

```
<div style="color: white; padding-left: 50px; margin-top: 30px;">
  <li style="color: white; " ><B>Menu Principal</B> </li>
</div>

<li class="active opened active has-sub" style="margin-top: 25px;">
  <a routerLink="/Construction-data">
    <i class="entypo-gauge"></i>
    <span class="title">Base de Données</span>
  </a>
</li>
  <ul class="visible">
    <li class="active">
      <a routerLink="/Construction-data">
        <span class="title">Conception</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
    <li>
      <a routerLink="/construction">
        <span class="title">Construction</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a routerLink="/Exploitation-data">
        <span class="title">Exploitation</span>
      </a>
    </li>


  </ul>
```

Comment: Could you give us HTML which shows the outer as well as the inner lists? Your HTML as it stands is not legal code. Also please give any relevant CSS or JS.

Comment: Did you solve this? or still need help? I'd like to help you

Comment: I need help please i didn't solve it